Background Styling Not Covering Entire Page in React Application
I'm encountering an issue with background styling in my React application. I've set up background styling for light and dark modes using CSS classes (light-mode and dark-mode). However, the background styling seems to only apply to the content area, rather than covering the entire page.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
// App.js

import React from "react";
import './App.css';

function App() {
    const [isDarkMode, setDarkMode] = React.useState(false);

    const toggleDarkMode = (checked) => {
        setDarkMode(checked);
    };

    return (
        <div className={isDarkMode ? 'dark-mode' : 'light-mode'}>
            {/* Content */}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

/* App.css */

.light-mode {
    background-color: #ffffff; /* Light mode background color */
}

.dark-mode {
    background-color: #000000; /* Dark mode background color */
}

Despite setting the background color for both light and dark modes, the background styling only covers the content area, leaving the rest of the page with the default background color.
I've tried various solutions, such as setting the min-height to 100vh for the root container, but the issue persists.
How can I ensure that the background styling covers the entire page, including areas without content?
Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

you've applied the class on the div inside the App component. So, only this element will receive the applied styling. If you want the entire page to be styled with bg, then please add this class to body element (or) make sure this div will always be 100% width and height of body

You could technically utilize CSS :has selectors if you don't have access to the html or body in js:
body {
   background-color: #FFFFFF; /* default to light mode */
}
body:has(.dark-mode) {
   background-color: #000000; /* Dark mode background color */
}

